# Active Record with Delegate and conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, delegates

Is it possible to use delegate in your Active Record model and use conditions like `:if` on it?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  delegate :company, :to => :master, :if => :has_master?

  belongs_to :master, :class_name => "User"

  def has_master?
    master.present?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

No, you can't, but you can pass the `:allow_nil => true` option to return nil if the master is nil.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate :company, :to => :master, :allow_nil => true

  # ...
end

user.master = nil
user.company 
# => nil

user.master = <#User ...>
user.company 
# => ...
```

Otherwise, you need to write your own custom method instead using the delegate macro for more complex options.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def company
    master.company if has_master?
  end

end
```

Comment: He could use the new try syntax: master.try(:company) which will return nil if master is nil.

Comment: try is only available in ruby 1.9

Comment: Try is available in any Ruby implementation via ActiveSupport but it requires ActiveSupport >= 2.3. Also, in this code I didn't see any real advantage of using try() so I went with the classic implementation.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to delegate the same method to two models, preferring to use one model over the other.  I used the :prefix option:

*from individual.rb*

```
delegate :referral_key, :email, :username, :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :approves_email, :approves_timeline, to: :user, allow_nil: true, prefix: true                                
delegate :email, :first_name, :last_name, to: :visitor, allow_nil: true, prefix: true

def first_name
  user.present? ? user_first_name : visitor_first_name
end
```