# How to conditionally delegate Active Records in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, delegates

Is it possible to delegate a function or series of functions to one of multiple other objects based on conditional logic?

Ex:

```
class Item
    has_one :thing
    has_one :other_thing

    delegate :foo,
             :bar
             to: :[thing or other_thing]
end
```

In this case, I would want the actions foo and bar to either be delegated to the thing, or the other thing based on some conditional logic.

Possibly related: [Active Record with Delegate and conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721433/active-record-with-delegate-and-conditions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

in addition to other objects, functions can be delegated to other functions.

Ex:

```
class Item
  has_one :thing
  has_one :other_thing

  delegate :foo,
           :bar
           to: :correct_thing

  def correct_thing
    [conditional] ? thing : other_thing
  end
end
```

Comment: one small change, there should be a comma after :bar

Answer (score 0):

Something like below:

```
class Item
  has_one :thing
  has_one :other_thing

  delegate :foo,
           :bar
           to: :thing if: thing_condition?

  delegate :foo,
           :bar
           to: :otherthing if: otherthing_condition?
end
```

Comment: There's no `if` option for [`delegate`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate) method.